# How do I know if my visual studio product key is permanent?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

also, How do I know what type of license is in my visual studio?
what are the types of product license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "product key" is always permanent. Just be sure you do not share it with other people.

To find your current license:

1. Click Help > About Visual Studio
2. Along the top there is a hyperlink -- "Product license information". Click that.

It will show you your current license.

For a quick and layman understanding of Visual Studio licensing, you can check this blog:

http://www.colinbowern.com/posts/visual-studio-licensing-in-a-nutshell

Cheers!